# Is it possible to create a Mac OS specific CSS to fix font difference?

Tags: css, macos, font-face

I'm working on a project with a designer and he insisted on using some specific font for titles and various elements in the page. So we're using a font kit to embed with @font-face.

It's working perfectly on PC (Firefox, IE 7 and 8, Chrome, Safari) but on Mac OS (Safari and Firefox) the fonts are not vertically aligned the same way. After looking on the Web, I didn't find any solution for this except "there always been differences between browsers and platforms, live with it".

I know that fonts are never rendered exactly the same across platforms, but this time it's not something like the font looks more bold or something like that. The font looks as if it's baseline is completely different between Windows and Mac OS X. On Mac OS, the font, at a size of 16px is 3px higher than on PC.

So I'm looking for a backup solution : is there a way to create a CSS specifically for Mac OS users? I do not want to target only Safari because Safari PC is ok, and Firefox Mac is not ok.

Or if you have a solution to fix the baseline difference that does not require a specific CSS file, I'd be happy to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting an explicit line-height doesn't fix the problem, you can serve different stylesheets to each browser using your backend and detecting the OS in your application (via the user agent). You can also do something in JS doing the same thing, but there will likely be a FOUC while JS loads the relevant styles.

Comment: Setting an explicit line-height doesn't fix the problem. Already tried it. Sniffing the user agent is not my first choice because it's so easy to modify it and then it wouldn't work...

Comment: I selected this one as the answer because server side browser sniffing is a lesser evil in my opinion. And it still works if the user used the weird "deactivate javascript" option.

Answer (score 16):

I'm afraid that browser/os sniffing is your only option. CSS itself has no knowledge of OS nor do i have ever heard of a css hack that targets osx specifically.

This is the easiest way for me to detect OSX and add the OSX class to the document body so you can override css styles for OSX specifically.

```
if(navigator.platform.match('Mac') !== null) {
    document.body.setAttribute('class', 'OSX');
}
```

Comment: `classList.add` would prevent existing classes from being overwritten.
`document.body.classList.add('OSX')`

Answer (score 1):

Same as @ChrisR  answer this is the easiest way for me to detect MAC and add the MAC class to the document body so you can override css styles for MAC specifically.

Additionally this keeps the current Body Class and just ADDS Mac on to it

```
if(navigator.platform.match('Mac') !== null) {
 document.body.setAttribute('class', document.body.className +' MAC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way.  http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

It detects the browser and os and allows you to specify classes specific to it.

Comment: That's basically the same as i posted, the only difference is that it adds a lot of extra code to sniff for other os'es too. In this case he only needs to target OSX which is far easier solved with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want close-to-perfect and painless, you're going to have to use the common fonts or fonts from an  online service such as Google's free font library or one of the for-pay font libraries. These fonts have been designed and tested to work on the web.

Experimenting and including fonts for the user's browser to download and try to display correctly is fine, but won't be perfect and won't be painless. Also, be very careful with licensing restrictions - make sure the fonts your designer wants to use are properly licensed for use on the client's website.

If you have to do browser sniffing and serve multiple stylesheets, at this point I'd say your design is broken and needs to be revised. Show https://fonts.google.com to your designer and see if he likes any of those - they work cross-platform in all modern browsers and some are very slick. EDIT: Oh, and they're free to use without worries of licensing.

Comment: Originally linked content can be viewed here: https://web.archive.org/web/20110124094318/http://code.google.com/webfonts/